# selectableItemBackground not working in PreferenceFragmentCompat item (Androidx)

Tags: android, styles, themes, androidx, preference

I have a `PreferenceFragmentCompat` and a `DrawerLayout` with a `NavigationView` are all in my `MainActivity`.
I try to use `?selectableItemBackground` to change my item background. It works on my `TextView` in `NavigationView`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feedback"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    ... />
```

(Dark Mode: Dark grey, Light Mode: White)

But it not working in my `PreferenceFragmentCompat`(Always white color).
Here's my theme and I use my own layout instead the default preference layout.

My Activity Theme.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/MyPreferenceTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="preferenceScreenStyle">...</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentCompatStyle">...</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentStyle">...</item>
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">...</item>
    <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/MyPreferenceStyle</item>
    <item name="checkBoxPreferenceStyle">...</item>
    <item name="switchPreferenceCompatStyle">...</item>
    <item name="preferenceCategoryTitleTextAppearance">...</item>
    <item name="switchPreferenceStyle">...</item>
    <item name="dialogPreferenceStyle">...</item>
    <item name="editTextPreferenceStyle">...</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentListStyle">...</item>
</style>
    
<style name="MyPreferenceStyle">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/preference_item</item>
</style>
```

My preference layout. The root is a `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusable="true"
    ...
```

How can I make it work?

```
androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1
```